# Create a results table from lists

Tags: python, dataset

I have a very simple (I think) question but can't find the answer. I'm used to R where creating and manipulating datasets is really straight forward.
I'm writing a python code that generates 3 lists of values like the following:

`names = [control, control, control, vinc, vinc, vinc]
area = [20.3, 23.4, 24.5, 65.45, 76.45, 34.65]
mean = [123, 232, 132, 65, 34, 65]`

I would like to output these lists as one csv file where each list is a column:

`names, area, mean
control, 20.3, 123
control, 23.4, 232
control, 24.5, 132
vinc, 65.45, 65
vinc, 76.45, 34
vinc, 34.65, 65`

It can't be really difficult to do this but I can't find the way.

Any idea??
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

names = ['control', 'control', 'control', 'vinc', 'vinc', 'vinc']
area = [20.3, 23.4, 24.5, 65.45, 76.45, 34.65]
mean = [123, 232, 132, 65, 34, 65]

op_file = open('output', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(op_file, delimiter=',')
csv_writer.writerow(['names', 'area', 'mean']) #print the header
for row in zip(names, area, mean):
    csv_writer.writerow(row) # write each row by zipping the three lists
op_file.close()
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wanted a space after the comma, in which case you might want `delimiter=', '`

Comment: @SethMMorton Delimiters have to be a 1-character string. You can not do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you save the list names somewhere i can't think of a way to automatically write the list's name in the file.

So assuming that, what you need is to open a file for non binary writing:

```
f=open('test.csv','w')
```

then write each line string by string including the carriage returns:

```
f.write('names area mean \n')
for i in range(len(names)):
    f.write(names[i]+', '+str(area[i])+', '+str(mean[i])+ '\n')
```

This should create what you need.